# Whatever happened to Nettles and Sheepstealer?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Looking at [the Histories & Lore video on "The Dance of Dragons"](https://youtu.be/WY_GyBuuf_c), had me wondering - do we know at all what happened after to Nettles, after she fled on her dragon Sheepstealer?

The history of Westeros video and the wiki don't seem to offer any answers - but then, I've not read the actual books or seen the full series: and so am wondering, if the actual text itself might have provided any answers or even just *clues* on the "what happened next" with this duo?

Comment: Your information comes from the show but you've tagged this books only. I know you're asking about if this is elaborated upon in the books but if you would accept show answers too you can add the show tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The show itself only gives the detail we see in that video which is, as you state, unfortunately short but can be expected from a 20 minute overview. As far as I am aware none of the other Histories & Lore videos mention the pair.

> **Oberyn Martell:** Rhaenyra now mistrusted all the dragonseeds, including the girl who rode with her husband Daemon, hunting Aemond in the Riverlands. She ordered the girl's head be sent to her. But there was a complication; as well as her dragon, the girl had taken to riding Daemon. When Daemon received the queen's order, he proclaimed it a queen's words and a whore's work. He sent the girl away at dawn, watching her and her dragon vanish into the morning mists.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 5 Histories & Lore, "The Dance of Dragons"</sub>

The books themselves didn't give too much detail on this and only hinted at legends until *Fire & Blood* came along which gives us more insight into what *could* have happened to them. The initial account of what happened is similar to what the show gives us.

> How the prince and his bastard girl spent their last night beneath Lord Mooton’s roof is not recorded, but as dawn broke they appeared together in the yard, and Prince Daemon helped Nettles saddle Sheepstealer one last time. It was her custom to feed him each day before she flew; dragons bend easier to their rider’s will when full. That morning she fed him a black ram, the largest in all Maidenpool, slitting the ram’s throat herself. Her riding leathers were stained with blood when she mounted her dragon, Maester Norren records, and “her cheeks were stained with tears.” No word of farewell was spoken betwixt man and maid, but as Sheepstealer beat his leathery brown wings and climbed into the dawn sky, Caraxes raised his head and gave a scream that shattered every window in Jonquil’s Tower. High above the town, Nettles turned her dragon toward the Bay of Crabs, and vanished in the morning mists, never to be seen again at court or castle.
>
> <sub>*Fire & Blood*, The Dying of the Dragons: Rhaenyra Triumphant</sub>

There are some accounts that when Daemon fell above the Gods Eye he survived and managed to make his way back to Nettles. However, Archmaester Gyldayn remarks that this is probably false and more of a *"charming song"*.

> That Prince Daemon died as well we cannot doubt. His remains were never found, but there are queer currents in that lake, and hungry fish as well. The singers tell us that the old prince survived the fall and afterward made his way back to the girl Nettles, to spend the remainder of his days at her side. Such stories make for charming songs, but poor history. Even Mushroom gives the tale no credence, nor shall we.
>
> <sub>*Fire & Blood*, The Dying of the Dragons: Rhaenyra Triumphant</sub>

It is believed that Sheepstealer and Nettles may have made their way to Crackclaw Point or the Mountains of the Moon. However, the last known sighting of the pair was in a cave in the Vale of Arryn when Ser Robert Rowan's men fought the pair briefly suffering heavy losses. Nettles and Sheepstealer were seen fleeing deeper in the Mountains of the Moon.  The wildlings of the mountains also tell tales of the "fire-witch" within but these may or may not be accurate.

> High in the mountains, the unthinkable happened one night as Lord Robert and his men huddled about their campfires. In the slopes above, a cave mouth was visible from the road, and a dozen men climbed up to see if it might offer them shelter from the wind. The bones scattered about the mouth of the cave might have given them pause, yet they pressed on…and roused a dragon.
>
> Sixteen men perished in the fight that followed, and threescore more suffered burns before the angry brown wyrm took wing and fled deeper into the mountains with “a ragged woman clinging to its back.” That was the last known sighting of Sheepstealer and his rider, Nettles, recorded in the annals of Westeros…though the wildlings of the mountains still tell tales of a “fire witch” who once dwelled in a hidden vale far from any road or village. One of the most savage of the mountain clan came to worship her, the storytellers say; youths would prove their courage by bringing gifts to her, and were only accounted men when they returned with burns to show that they had faced the dragon woman in her lair.
>
> <sub>*Fire & Blood*, The Lysene Spring and the End of Regency</sub>